# Dynamic page URL

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I have a page with URL that is dynamic. Let's call it *view post* page. URL for *post 1* is `site.com/post/1` and for *post 2* is `site.com/post/2`.

This is what I do at the moment to check if I am at the right page.

The page:

```
class ViewPostPage
  include PageObject

  def self.url
    "site.com/post/"
  end
end
```

Cucumber step:

```
on(ViewPostPage) do |page|
  @browser.url.should == "#{page.class.url}#{@id}"
end
```

Is there a better way? Do you even bother checking the entire URL, or just the `site.com/post/` part?

I am using the latest [page-object](https://rubygems.org/gems/page-object) gem (0.6.6).

## Update

Even bigger problem is going directly to the page that has dynamic URL.

The page:

```
class ViewPostPage
  include PageObject

  def self.url
    "site.com/post/"
  end
  page_url url
end
```

Cucumber step:

```
visit ViewPostPage
```

What I do now is to change the Cucumber step to:

```
@browser.goto "#{ViewPostPage.url}#{@id}"
```

It would be great if there was a way for the page to know it's ID, but I have not figured out yet how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the url for the page using the method current_url.  On your test above are you trying to determine if you are on the correct page?  If that is the case I might suggest using one of the two "expected" methods - expected_title and expected_element.

The page_url method is more than likely not the choice for you if you need to navigate to a url dynamically.  What you might try instead is add a method to your page that does something like this:

```
class ViewPostPage
  include PageObject

  URL = "site.com/post/"

  expected_title  "The expected title"

  def navigate_to_post_with_id(id)
    navigate_to "#{URL}/#{id}"
  end

end
```

And in your test

```
on_page(ViewPostPage) do |page|
  page.navigate_to_post_with_id @id
  page.should have_expected_title
end
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: `expected_title` and `expected_element` do not help because I want to check URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to check dynamic URL in the Page Object gem.

Use the below code:

> class ViewPostPage
>
> ```
>   include PageObject
>
>       expected_url  "The expected URL"
>
>   def initialize
>
>      has_expected_url?
>
>    end
> ```
>
> end

It'll help you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `#page_url` is for opening corresponding page along with page object initialization. To verify you're on correct page, you can try to use `#expected_title` method.

Also, maybe it'll be useful for you. When symbol is passed to `#page_url`, it calls corresponding method, so'd better use it. I haven't tried it, but here are few links for you.

- Original [issue](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/spec/page-object/accessors_spec.rb#L136) on GitHub
- [Specs](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/spec/page-object/accessors_spec.rb#L136)
- [Documentation of #page_url](http://rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/0.6.6/PageObject/Accessors%3apage_url)

Comment: I am not using `#page_url` when checking URL. I have removed it from the example, it was there by mistake. `#expected_title` will check page title, right? I want to check the URL.